# How do you indicate two people or three people or more saying the same thing simultaneously in a movie script?

Tags: formatting, script

[image]

How do you indicate two people or three people or more saying the same thing simultaneously in a movie script? There's a place where you put the character name before a dialogue, but what happens when two or three people or more say the same thing at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the characters listed with commas and I think one time listed with commas and the word "and". For just two people speaking at once I guess you could do either, just stay consistent with the rest of the script. (note the "and" is in lowercase to make it clearly different than the character names)

Ex1:

> DAVE, JULIA, CARL
>
> Watch out!

Ex2:

> Phillip, JACKIE, and MELANIE
>
> Happy birthday!